# Как вывести определённое время? discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я хочу чтобы когда люди писали .work и потом еще раз писали эту команду, то у них выводилось:
**Вы устали! Приходите через 00d 00h 00m 00s**
или
**Вы устали! Приходите в 20:30:14 PM**

Как это сделать? Я перепробовал кучу вариантов, но не могу. Помогите.

Comment: добавляйте свою "кучу вариантов" в вопрос ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1279261/edit)) и вам обязательно подскажут, что не так

Comment: слегка не понятен вопрос. Думаю, datetime вам поможет с временем